# Constant-weight code for error correction

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I need some [Constant-weight code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code) for error correction. Understanding how these codes generated is really hard for me. The papers of this topic are focus on lower bound and upper bound. What I need is just some constant-weight codes for error correction. And there is something wrong of the [table](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/codes/Andw/index.html) website thus I can't open it. Can somebody give me some constant-weight code with hamming distance at least 5 ?

Comment: The Internet Archive is always good for dead links: http://web.archive.org/web/20121101011533/http://www2.research.att.com/~njas/codes/Andw/index.html

Comment: Many thanks. And I find that no trivial construction exists right now.